# UITableview getting custom cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im about to develop a custom cell in a tableview using the method:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

my concern before i start this is the following.

The cell will contain three labels, in some cases very short labels, in some cases very long labels.

The effect this has is the height of the cell could alter considerably.

Is there anyway i can get the height of the cell of the

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

call

or is there a better method of what I'm trying to do.

thanks

Comment: you need to change height of the cell?is that dynamic height table?

Comment: ideally, some cells will be tiny, very short text, others really long, but if i have them all at maximum height then the really short ones look awful so much empty space if that make sense

Comment: to put it into perspective, short label will be 2 lines long, long label can be 40-50 lines

Comment: you can set height of the table cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: exactly, how can i get the height of my custom cell for that call

Answer (score 0):

The better method is calculate the height before rendering the view.

For example you got three labels with the following data:

1. Title
2. Subtitle
3. Description

What I will do is to calculate the size of each string by:

```
UIFont *yourFont = // [UIFont ...]
CGSize stringBoundingBox = [someString sizeWithFont:yourFont];
```

I will then store that size in my stack of data with the key of the corresponding data (title, subtitle, description), the keys will be

1. titleSize //for the title
2. subTitleSize //for the subTitle
3. descriptionSize

The item of the NSArray will look like:

```
 @{
  @"titleSize" : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:(CGSize)titleSize],
  @"subTitleSize" : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:(CGSize)subTitleSize],
  @"descriptionSize" : [NSValue valueWithCGSize:(CGSize)descriptionSize],
  @"title" : title, //the NSString data
  @"subTitle" : subTitle, //the NSString data
  @"descriptionSize" : descriptionSize, //the NSString data

 }
```

And in here you can have:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath        *)indexPath{
      NSDictionary *item = stack[indexPath.row];
      CGSize titleSize = [item[@"titleSize"] CGSizeValue];
      CGSize subTitleSize = [item[@"subTitleSize"] CGSizeValue];
      CGSize descriptionSize = [item[@"descriptionSize"] CGSizeValue];

      //calculate the correct height and stuff.
       ...........

   return height;
 }
```

You can create some constants or methods to get the margins and paddings you will be having.

The beauty of this solution is that you will be calculating once. But if your data updates for a given item, you need to recalculate your sizes and reload your tableview.